# Can't connect from gRPC client to server

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, grpc, grpc-go

Getting an error when trying to connect to gRPC server:

> rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 172.20.0.3:50051: connect: connection refused

Client and Server are running in different docker containers here is the code and details:

Server:

```
grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
walletpb.RegisterWalletServiceServer(grpcServer, grpcapi.NewWalletServiceServer(configApp)) // Ideally should be interface
go func() {
    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:50051")
    util.FatalIfError(err)
    util.FatalIfError(grpcServer.Serve(listen))
}()
```

Client:

```
var opts []grpc.DialOption
opts = append(opts, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))

conn, err := grpc.Dial("app:50051", opts...)
if err != nil {
    util.FatalIfError(err)
}
defer conn.Close()

// Initialize the WalletService client
client := walletpb.NewWalletServiceClient(conn)

// Timeout after 5 seconds if the server doesn't respond
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()

// Call the GetBalance method and receive a response
response, err := client.GetBalance(ctx, &walletpb.BalanceRequest{UserId: "user123"})
util.FatalIfError(err)
```

Dockerfile.backend

```
FROM golang:1.20 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o backend ./cmd/backend/main.go

FROM alpine:3.18

COPY --from=builder /app/backend /backend

CMD ["/backend"]
```

Dockerfile.client:

```
FROM golang:1.20 as builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o client ./cmd/client/main.go

FROM alpine:3.18

COPY --from=builder /app/client /client

CMD ["/client"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backend
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50051:50051"
    depends_on:
      - redis
  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.client
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
      - "50051:50051"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - app
  redis:
    image: "redis:7.2-alpine"
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

From the error I can see that server's address is correct (172.20.0.3:50051). Maybe I'm missing something obvious here? Thank you.

**Update:** In order to add more information to context.

Here is util.FatalIfError(..) function:

```
func FatalIfError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal().Err(err).Send()
    }
}
```

And wallet.proto file:

service WalletService {
rpc GetBalance (BalanceRequest) returns (BalanceResponse);
}

```
message BalanceRequest {
  string user_id = 1;
}

message BalanceResponse {
  double balance = 1;
}
```

Comment: Your code, while comprehensive, isn't a minimally reproducible example: we don't have `walletpb` nor your `util` module. This makes it more challenging for you to get help.

Comment: The go routine in Server will run and then will then be terminated upon code completion. Is your actual code allowing this go routine to continue running (the server)? If not, that's one problem.

Comment: I recreated your solution using [`health`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/health) and it worked for me with the exception that I don't have Docker Compose installed (although that config looks correct). I was able to run the client and server as-is and they connect/work correctly, and using your Dockerfiles to build images. It's either something in your code that we can't access, the errant Go routine, or something I'm missing in the Docker Compose.

Comment: [`ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) is a little confusing with Docker Compose but these mirror `--publish`. You need only use `ports` in Docker Compose if you want to expose container ports to the host network i.e. outside of e.g. `mynetwork`. They're not needed for your app to work as described, connecting within `mynetwork`. They may be there for your debugging but are otherwise unnecessary

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin for your comments. Added information about FatalIfError and .proto file to to the question. Yes, server runs in goroutine. Good point regarding to ports, but didn't make much difference running without them.

Comment: Yes, the `ports` explanation was just FYI not a proposed solution. I installed Docker Compose and it works for me. You won't be able to duplicate the `ports` values of `50051:50051` on both `app` and `client`. Because `ports` binds to the host's ports (and there's only one e.g. `50051` on the host), you can't duplicate these. This value is only valid for `app` because `client` doesn't expose the port.

Comment: To debug, I encourage you to try running the binaries locally (i.e. `go run ./cmd/server` ..) and prove that works. If it does, then run the containers (i.e. `docker run ... --publish=50051:50051/tcp ...`). You'll need to run `client` using `docker run --net=host ...` so that it can access the host-bound `50051`. If both these work, there's something incorrect in your `docker-compose.yml`. Good luck!